# How does react manage CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs

So for example for the HTML we have the index.html file on the public folder that we can clearly see. Now my question is how bout CSS. I have CSS for each of my components of a react application but I want to use things like variables and constants that run across an application.
Someone explain this to me.

Comment: Why do you have a CSS file for each component not a single one for the whole project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define all variables and constants that you want to use across your project, in one file and import in `App.js` or `index.js` as a css file.

App.js

```
import "./style.css"
```

styles (classes) that you define in this file, are accessed all over your project.